# What is the correct way to manage a map of child actors in Akka?

Tags: akka

Suppose I have an actor who is responsible for routing messages to a collection of child actors, based on some key, so that it's internal state looks like this:

```
Map<String, ActorRef> children;
```

As well as routing messages, the parent actor must support add and remove operations:

```
if(message instanceOf Add) {
    children.put(message.getKey(), getContext().actorOf(childProps, message.getKey()));
} else if (message instanceOf Remove) {
    getContext().stop(children.get(message.getKey());
    children.remove(message.getKey());
} else if (message instanceOf RouteToChild) {
    children.get(message.getKey()).forward(message, getContext());
}
```

Hopefully the above code is enough to get the general idea of what I'm trying to do. Note that I am using the map key as the name of the child actor. The problem is that the above pattern does not handle the case of Add, Remove and Add messages in quick succession for the same key - it often fails on the second Add with:

```
akka.actor.InvalidActorNameException: actor name [...] is not unique!
```

Obviously, stopping the child actor on Remove messages is asynchronous which is why it doesn't work, and I'm struggling to see what the solution is. I have noted the following point from the [Akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/addressing.html#Reusing_Actor_Paths), which describes my problem exactly:

> While it is possible to create an actor at a later time with an identical path [...] this is not good practice [...].
>
> It may be the right thing to do in very specific circumstances, but make sure to confine the handling of this precisely to the actor’s supervisor, because that is the only actor which can reliably detect proper deregistration of the name, before which creation of the new child will fail.

So, is reusing the actor path (using the map key as the actor name) the right thing to do here? If so, how do I "reliably detect proper deregistration of the name"? If not, should I just assign a UUID to each actor name? Could this cause problems if the children were persistent actors (as new child with same persistence id could be created before previous child is properly terminated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `watch` the state of the `ActorRef` to get a notification when the Actor has been terminated.  An ActorRef is considered "stale" if a termination has been dispatched but your supervisor hasn't received the confirmation yet.

If an `Add` comes in for a stale Actor then you just send the Add to yourself again with the hopes that the termination will eventually complete:

```
HashSet<String> staleActorRefs = new HashSet<String>();

if(message instanceOf Add) {
    if(staleActorRefs.contains(message.getKey())) {
      getSelf().forward(message, getContext()); 
    } else {
      children.put(message.getKey(), getContext().watch(getContext().actorOf(childProps, message.getKey())));
    }
} else if (message instanceOf Remove) {
    getContext().stop(children.get(message.getKey());
    staleActorRefs.add(message.getKey());
    children.remove(message.getKey());
} else if (message instanceOf RouteToChild) {
    children.get(message.getKey()).forward(message, getContext());
} else if (message instanceOf Terminated) {
    staleActorRefs.remove(message.actor().path().name());
}
```

This recursive messaging means that your supervisor will continually try to Add until the termination is complete.

There will be a problem if a `RouteToChild` arrives while an ActorRef is stale, but the solution to that situation is open ended and was not specified in the question...

**Don't Do It**

Having said all that, I agree with the quote in the question: "this is not good practice".

Go with UUIDs and save yourself the headache...